# How to get a different return type according to the object accessing key?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let me simply put it like,

```js
interface PlanValue {
  planName: string;
  startDate: string;
} 

type DeviceKey = 'pc' | 'mobile' | 'laptop';

type PlanType = Record<DeviceKey, PlanValue>

interface Subscription {
  valid: boolean;
  plan: PlanType;
}
```

Let's say that a new device key called `Kiosk` is added to `DeviceKey` type.

But the return type of this key should be boolean.

For example

```js
const subsc1: Subscription = new Subscription();
const subsc2: Subscription = new Subscription();
console.log(subsc1.plan.pc)    // type should be PlanValue
console.log(subsc2.plan.Kiosk) // type should be boolean
```

I can't change the `Subscription.plan` type to `PlanType | boolean` because it will break other codes that are referring to this type.

How can I get a different return type according to the accessing key during the runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types):

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=17&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoBs4gGp3QVxQG8BYAKGWQAdMQA5OAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG5ylTnChgAInEhtO3EP3IBfZOXJgAnlRRiIAN2BIA0hDXIAvMgDkVBBeQAfS4wD2AI2DoIthxcxUwTqgsBMlUNFAwsABUws2QAJQgEJygAEwAebT1DYwAaNFpcAggAPmQAMmQiZANgJ3YAazYXJycPLGQFYPJQSFhEFABlfBd2BG4-WpBKwWQdPGAUppa2kGDKGiw2CJBozWCFFTIUxMwoFCSQTg42IZGx4AmnVfJ2ADoNkHeEZAB6H-ysIVCC93rRXjU6vVfv9mq0IFhyEA)

```ts
interface PlanValue {
  planName: string;
  startDate: string;
} 

type DeviceKey = 'pc' | 'mobile' | 'laptop';

type PlanType = Record<DeviceKey, PlanValue> & { Kiosk: boolean };

interface Subscription {
  valid: boolean;
  plan: PlanType;
}

declare const s: Subscription;
s.plan.pc // PlanValue
s.plan.Kiosk // boolean
```

Comment: What an easy way to implement! will check more about intersection type that you attached. Thanks.